Define Routing Outside of the Project in Remix React
I'm using a monorepo and I wanted to move the routes outside of the project.
Would it be possible? How would you do that? I'm using Remix and Vite and remix-flat-routes.
Do you adjust it in the vite.config.ts?

vite.config.ts
import { vitePlugin as remix } from "@remix-run/dev";
import { installGlobals } from "@remix-run/node";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import tsconfigPaths from "vite-tsconfig-paths";
import { resolve } from "path";
import { flatRoutes } from "remix-flat-routes"

installGlobals();

const appDir = resolve(__dirname, '../../../packages');

export default defineConfig({
    server: {
        port: 3000,
    },
    plugins: [
        remix({
            ignoredRouteFiles: ["**/*.css"],
            routes: async defineRoutes => {
                return flatRoutes('routes', defineRoutes, { appDir })
              },
        }),
        tsconfigPaths(),
    ],
    define: {
        "process.env": process.env,
    },
});

